# preg replace text outside of a tags

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

i don't know anything about regex. but i need to fix this.
i want to replace all text outside of a tags.(if there is any tags)

this is my code:

```
$entry = preg_replace("'\(find: (.*)\)'Ui","(find: <a href=\"/search/\\1/\"><b>\\1</b></a>)",$entry);
```

it should replace (find: foo) outside of html tags.

i tried this, but didn't work. because i don't understand regex :(

```
preg_replace("'([^<]+?>)\(find: (.*)\)([^<]+?>)'Ui","(find: <a href=\"/find/\\1/\"><b>\\1</b></a>)",$entry);
```

thank you in advance. :)

**EDIT:** this is my example:

```
// some users do this. and it brokes the text.

$entry = "blablabla (find: (user: bora)) blablabla ";

function entry($entry) {
    $entry = preg_replace("'\(find: (.*)\)'Ui","<a href=\"/find/\\1/\"><b>\\1</b></a>",$entry);
    $entry = preg_replace("'\(user: (.*)\)'Ui","(user: <a href=\"/user/\\1/\"><b>\\1</b></a>)",$entry);
    $entry = stripslashes($entry);
    return $entry;
}
```

Comment: Use  DOMXPath to extract text nodes that contain what you are looking for.

Comment: You should *never* parse HTML with regex. Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: If this is HTML, then all text is wrapped in tags, ultimately by the `body` or `html` tags. So what do you mean?

Comment: thank you for quick replies. but i don't know any of those. i'm just an amatour. i bought the script and found this problem. can you help me for regex?

Comment: @trincot $entry is only text. but there is multiple preg_replace.

Comment: @BoraYüksel: if `$entry` is only text at the beginning, you should try a different approach. Could you tell us more? (a representative example of original text, and the different changes you need to do)

Comment: So you are saying that you start with plain text, and then after a few replaces you have HTML in it, but could have a case where `(find: ...)` occurs within those HTML tags? But you created those HTML tags yourself with that content... I am missing the point. You should be able to find the correct order of applying the replacements so that you are sure there will never be a match within the tags you generated with previous replacements.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte i added an example. can you check it please? :)

Comment: @trincot can you check my example please? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/18157

Comment: it's not a representative example of the original text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would prevent the problems you describe:

```
function linkit($match) {
    $item = urlencode($match[1]); // "user" or "find", made safe for URL
    $href = urlencode($match[2]); // part after ":", made safe for URL
    $content = htmlentities($match[2]); // part after ":" made safe for HTML
    return "<a href='/$item/$href/'><b>$content</b></a>";
}

function entry($entry) {
    // Use one replace operation for both "find" or "user":
    // For each match the function linkit is called. 
    // These 3 characters may not occur before closing parentheses:
    //    ( < >
    $entry = preg_replace_callback("'\((find|user): ([^(<>]*?)\)'ui", 
                                   'linkit', $entry);
    return $entry;
}

$entry = "blablabla (find: (user: bora)) blablabla ";
echo entry($entry);
```

Output:

```
blablabla (find: <a href='/user/bora/'><b>bora</b></a>) blablabla
```

As you can see the *"(find: ...)"* was not replaced, because there was another opening parenthesis before the first closing one. Even if you would call *entry()* again on this result, it would not change, because there is a less-than sign occurring before the closing parenthesis of the *"(find :...."*.